# After moving a module to another folder , i cannot clear reminiscent module paths

Tags: 8

I have moved the contrib module pagerer from

> /sites/my_site/modules

to

> /modules/contrib

It breaks the site as some files are unaccessible

> /platforms/drupal8-development/sites/recherche-dev.univ-amu.fr/modules/pagerer/src/Entity/PagererPreset.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in require()

i guess i would need to perform a registry rebuild but i don't know how.

drush rr outputs

> The drush command 'rr' could not be found

Comment: `drush cr` should be all you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving module location](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185958/moving-module-location)

Comment: drush cr is not enough. i do a drush pm-uninstall then drush cr , empty all cache_table +cahe tags ,its fine, but when i enable the module the same wrong path error reappear !? where can this be stored?

Comment: Trying going to /rebuild.php maybe something is stopping the drush rebuild happening https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21rebuild.php/8.6.x

Comment: how can i execute the rebuild.php ? mydomainname/rebuild.php returns a 404

Comment: Restart the server to clear APC cache or memcache.

Answer (score 1):

i have ended up putting in local.settings.php

```
   /**
 * Class Loader.
 *
 * If the APC extension is detected, the Symfony APC class loader is used for
 * performance reasons. Detection can be prevented by setting
 * class_loader_auto_detect to false, as in the example below.
 */
$settings['class_loader_auto_detect'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal stores a cached version of the container at the cache_container table. This table contains, among other things, the list of module paths.

For most cases running `drush cr` should be enough but if you see that even `drush cr` crashes then you will need to create a database update like this in an already installed module:

```php
/**
 * Clears all caches after moving modules from modules to modules/contrib.
 */
function mymodule_update_8100(&$sandbox) {
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

And then run `drush updb -y`.